# Geocoding adress doesnot give latitude and longitude

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Im using this URL `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="ADDRESS"&sensor=false?key=APIKey` of our prjct. But not getting results. It shows me error eventhough I use an API Key

```
{
   "error_message" : "Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Unable to understand where am I going wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' suggests that you have made too many requests on that API key. Log into the console and check the status of your API key and number of requests. There is no coding issue here.

Comment: Try it in Postman @Honey Because i checked your url it is correct and parameters are all correct.

Comment: @Scriptable Is there a way to avoid that error and increasing the limit

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav can u plz let me know what is Postman

Comment: Login to the console and see what it says, you may need to upgrade to a paid plan. This site is for coding advice/support, we can't really help with third party issues, check the status of your account and see if it suggests you upgrade.

Comment: It's possibly easier to use Apple's API for this. Certainly you don't need an API key. See CLGeocoder and geocodeAddressString(…)

Comment: @Honey Postman is complete API development environment, you can put url and there parameters and you can check your response and response code what it return from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="ADDRESS"&sensor=false?key=APIKey` is wrong.

Have a look at this part `?key=APIKey`, it should be `&key=APIKey`. Also note that address parameter shouldn't have `"` symbols and sensor parameter is not required anymore, it was deprecated long time ago.

The request should be

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ADDRESS&key=APIKey`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it's clearly says,

> "Keyless access to Google Maps Platform"

to use Google API's you need to register the application, and request API services. 
therefore you will have an

access to your key to use, keep in mind all the API services requires **Client Key** and you have to provide it in the **Request** otherwise you can't use any of google API's.

you can generate Key after Registering [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?__utma=102347093.1394468406.1533021384.1537789513.1537789513.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1537789513&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1537789513.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)%7Cutmccn=(direct)%7Cutmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=157493562&_ga=2.62356140.1470683524.1537789508-1394468406.1533021384#get-started)